# nifi 1.11.4 version taking longer time to load

Tags: apache-nifi

```
After migrating flows from 1.8 to 1.11, The env taking 10 minutes to load the flow and up the cluster.
it was 2 min in 1.8 env to load the flow and up the cluster.

few warning in logs which i am suspecting the delay.
```

but i am seeing these warning in 1.8 env also  Could you please let me know the issue.

```
 WARN [Process Cluster Protocol Request-10] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Failed processing protocol message from “**HOSTIP address**”com due to org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed marshalling protocol message in response to message type: CONNECTION_REQUEST due to javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed marshalling protocol message in response to message type: CONNECTION_REQUEST due to javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.impl.SocketProtocolListener.dispatchRequest(SocketProtocolListener.java:184)
        at org.apache.nifi.io.socket.SocketListener$2$1.run(SocketListener.java:136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:980)
        at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.jaxb.JaxbProtocolContext$1.marshal(JaxbProtocolContext.java:86)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.impl.SocketProtocolListener.dispatchRequest(SocketProtocolListener.java:182)
        ... 4 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:357)
                ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:319)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
2020-08-13 00:23:51,002 WARN [Process Cluster Protocol Request-6] org.apache.nifi.io.socket.SocketListener Dispatching socket request encountered exception due to: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Second suspect warning:
WARN [Process Cluster Protocol Request-6] org.apache.nifi.io.socket.SocketListener Dispatching socket request encountered exception due to: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)
at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:120)
at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:95)
at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:156)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.flushBuffer(UTF8XmlOutput.java:418)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.text(UTF8XmlOutput.java:371)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Base64Data.writeTo(Base64Data.java:314)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.text(UTF8XmlOutput.java:312)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:356)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$PcdataImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:191)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:254)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:341)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:328)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:256)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:110)
at org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.jaxb.JaxbProtocolContext$1.marshal(JaxbProtocolContext.java:75)
at org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.impl.SocketProtocolListener.dispatchRequest(SocketProtocolListener.java:182)
at org.apache.nifi.io.socket.SocketListener$2$1.run(SocketListener.java:136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Comment: ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-14] o.a.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroup Failed to synchronize StandardProcessGroup[identifier=*] with Flow Registry because could not retrieve version 1 of flow with identifier ** in bucket **
org.apache.nifi.registry.client.NiFiRegistryException: Error retrieving flow snapshot: The specified flow ID does not exist in this bucket.
        at org...impl.JerseyFlowSnapshotClient.get(JerseyFlowSnapshotClient.java:97)
        at org....flow.RestBasedFlowRegistry.getFlowContents(RestBasedFlowRegistry.java:211)

Comment: at org....flow.RestBasedFlowRegistry.getFlowContents(RestBasedFlowRegistry.java:225)
        at org....StandardProcessGroup.synchronizeWithFlowRegistry(StandardProcessGroup.java:3537)
        at org....FlowController$5.run(FlowController.java:903)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)

Comment: Could you provide heap configuration?